# Amplify: Not Authorized to access functionName on type Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

When doing queries to the AppSync API from one of our lambda functions, we're getting the error: "Not Authorized to access functionName on type Query".

The tricky part is that the lambda function is configured to have access to api Queries, Mutations and subscription, and the same code is working for another similar lambda function.

There is one difference, however. The working lambda function is called by a Cognito user and is linked as a lambda resolver in the api. The lambda function that is NOT working is triggered by API Gateway (REST). However, they both use defaultProvider() with IAM authorization for accessing AppSync so I don't understand why one of them is working and the other is not.

I'm sure there is something in the authorization flow I do not understand here, any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code we use to create our Apollo Client:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import * as WebSocket from "ws";

import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  HttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
} from "@apollo/client/core";
import { createAuthLink } from "aws-appsync-auth-link";
import { createSubscriptionHandshakeLink } from "aws-appsync-subscription-link";

import { defaultProvider } from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node";
import { global } from "@apollo/client/utilities/globals";

export const createApolloClient = (url: string, region: string) => {
  // Assign global WebSocket if none is defined
  // (Required for non-browser runtimes e.g. Node)
  if (global.WebSocket === undefined) {
    Object.assign(global, { WebSocket });
  }

  const linkArgs = {
    url,
    region,
    auth: {
      type: "AWS_IAM" as "AWS_IAM",
      credentials: defaultProvider(),
    },
  };

  const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: url, fetch: fetch as any });
  const link = ApolloLink.from([
    createAuthLink(linkArgs),
    createSubscriptionHandshakeLink(linkArgs, httpLink),
  ]);

  return new ApolloClient({ link, cache: new InMemoryCache() });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was due to a bug in Amplify, and that despite pushing the changes, the API hadn't actually updated to reflect the authorization changes. To resolve this issue, a comment was added to `schema.graphql` which resolved the issue.

Known issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/679

Comment: Could you provide more detail in this answer please?
What was the comment and change required to get it working?
The documentation in AWS is awful.

Comment: From what I understand it doesn't really matter. As long as there has been any change to the schema.graphql and it triggers an API update. Make sure that when you run "amplify status" it shows that the API should indeed update. Issue also sometimes may be fixed by doing "amplify checkout env <your_envname>"